# How was the "ROS Package by License" generated?

Tags: ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an interesting page titled [ROS Package by License](https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/licenses.html) still hosted on `docs.ros.org`, although there's no newer version than for ROS Diamondback.

This was probably output by some script running on "the old" ROS buildfarm (or perhaps even by hand?), but I've not been able to find something similar so I was wondering if that script would still be around somewhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319902/how-was-the-%22ros-package-by-license%22-generated?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I found this script : https://github.com/ros/documentation/blob/electric/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/licenseindex.py

It's used in this script : [https://github.com/ros/documentation/blob/electric/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/**init**.py](https://github.com/ros/documentation/blob/electric/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/__init__.py)

To populate the template at : https://github.com/ros/documentation/blob/electric/rosdoc/templates/license-index.html

Everything is still on the electric tag and diamondback tag in rosdoc : https://github.com/ros/documentation/tree/electric

But it need a lot of refreshing (The license name are hardcoded), it has been deleted by kwc here : https://github.com/ros/documentation/commit/cb6b713636b774cfa1c2bd7bdb94a20c0a16e6af#diff-23aa12dcb58c651d407414f40b5f8afd

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2019-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-30**:
Thanks. That seems to be the code indeed.